# No se me suben los nuevos cambios a git

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-pull

Estoy comenzando a usar git, así que perdón si es algún error tonto, pero no he podido encontrar la respuesta.

Hice git pull (lo cual creo que no hizo nada) y después de hacer algunos cambios a mi programa, traté de hacer:

```
git add .
git commit -m "comentario"
```

pero al poner el comentario me sale lo siguiente:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Y en visual studio me sale que no se han subido los cambios.

He intentado hacer más cambios, y también a añadir otra carpeta nueva dentro, para ver si se subía. Pero sólo sube la carpeta nueva, y el resto de cambios los deja como están.

este es el status

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Y en el código (Visual Studio Code) se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hacer git push (después de agregar el comentario) o hacer git status, me daba como respuesta lo mismo anterior.

Comment: el `.`  se debe separar del `add`..... en todo caso, cual es la salida de `git status`? Edita la pregunta y ponlo ahi, por favor.

Comment: `git pull` sí hace algo. No tendría sentido que haya comandos que no hagan nada. Que su efecto no sea visible es otra cosa.

Comment: hacer git status me decía que los cambios ya estaban subidos y que no había nada nuevo. Al final, se me ha resuelto solo (?). Estuve haciendo cambios en el código (sin subir a git por el error este) hasta que decidí hacer una copia en mi portátil para guardar mi progreso. No sé cómo, pero todos los cambios que había hecho se borraron y git volvía a ir bien. A saber qué era...

Comment: Pasa que commit != push

Answer (score 2):

Si haces un commit con todos los cambios hasta el momento y enseguida escribes [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status), obtienes el mensaje:

> On branch main
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Es decir, con ese comando solo verificas si hay cambios sin registrar en un commit.

Como mencionas, los commits no se cargan porque hay un paso que te está faltando:

```
git push
```

Con [ese comando](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) los cargas al repositorio remoto.

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) es su contraparte. Descarga los cambios del repositorio remoto y los incorpora en la rama actual.

---

Si lo prefieres puedes usar alguna interfaz gráfica. Por ejemplo, Github Desktop o incluso la de Visual Studio Code.

Sugiero que mires algunos tutoriales para que comprendas bien cómo funciona. Los de [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials) me parecen bastante buenos y no son tan extensos.

Answer (score 0):

Me paso un error similar cuando recién comencé, me salia lo siguiente:

> $ git status  On branch main  Your branch is up to date with
> 'origin/main'.   Untracked files:
> (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
> ./
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Era raro para mi porque solo decía que se había creado un directorio raíz "./", y el problema era que estaba dentro de una carpeta del proyecto donde hice el git init, por ejemplo, hice el init en Carpeta_Padre pero navegue dentro de esta carpeta y dentro de las subcarpetas hice el git status, solo tienes que volverte a la padre donde hiciste el git init y ya te saldrán los cambios realizados en esa carpeta.

Es un error un poco torpe el mio je, pero quizá le pase a alguien. Saludos.